# visual basic save failed due to out of memory or disk space

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, vba

I'm editing a macro in Word 2007 in Windows XP. When I try to save this macro, I get the following error message:

> save failed due to out of memory or disk space

Now, I have plenty of disk space available, so I think that this is a lie.

However, when I try to edit/save the macro on another machine, it succeeds.

I've tried to repair the Office 2007 install.
I've uninstalled/reinstalled Office 2007 and applied all available updates.
I've uninstalled/reinstalled Office 2007 without applying any updates.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that errors in the disk data structures are causing this.  In Windows Explorer, right click the drive letter, choose **Properties**, go to the **Tools** tab, click **Check Now**, make sure that **Automatically fix filesystem errors** is enabled and click **Start**.  Depending on the drive, Windows may tell you that you need to restart to perform the check; if it says this, you'll need to restart Windows.